# GAE and Facebook Connect: How to get age and gender of user?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with Google App Engine and Facebook Connect.

I have found Facebook Python SDK at https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/tree/master/examples/appengine and it has some examples for basic user login and getting their names and friends.

How can I get the user's other information?  I would like to have their **age** and **gender** for my app to work properly.  I know it requires additional permissions to get that information but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need any permission for Gender property of the user and for the Age you can calculate by Subtracting the User's Date of birth by current Date.

For Date of Birth you need `user_birthday` [Extended Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

If you want to know how to request permissions specify them in `scope` query parameter like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=user_birthday
```

Check out the example here on github  https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py

I dont know python myself but, If you are using the python sdk then you can request user information like this (inferred from the example above)

```
profile = graph.get_object("me")
gender = profile["gender"]
dateofbirth = profile["birthday"]
```

now you can get age by subtracting user date from current date.

Comment: Thanks, but I kind of got that far on my own.  The profile object returned does have gender (I actually didn't realize that before), but it doesn't include birthday even after I added scope=user_birthday to the URL (https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={valid access token}&scope=user_birthday) there was still no birthday in the returned profile object.

Comment: No you don't get new permissions that way... You will have to reauthorize your application by the user with new scope settings... Request extended permissions as i have mentioned in my answer... Good Luck.. :)